# Join 2 timeseries tables with different frequencies with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, time-series

I am trying to join a table with daily data with a table with quarterly or longer frequency data, matching on id and date. I believe I need a full outer join e.g. I need all the daily data and the quarterly data aligned by date, with nulls for quarterly data if not available.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```sql
select daily.id, daily.date, daily.value as dly_value, quarterly.value as qly_value
from daily
full outer join quarterly on daily.id = quarterly.id
and daily.date = quarterly.date
where daily.type = 'dly_type'
and quarterly.type = 'qly_type'
and daily.id = 16
```

But this only returns the rows that match the quarterly dates. If I omit the line matching on the dates, I get all the daily data, plus the quarterly data but not aligned by date.

Clearly I'm missing something obvious, but I'm clearly not asking google the question in the right way!

Comment: Share some data rows from both tables and tell us what your expected output is for given rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a `left join`, not a `full join` -- all the daily data with matching values for the quarterly:

```
select d.id, d.date, d.value as dly_value, q.value as qly_value
from daily d left join
     quarterly q
     on d.id = q.id and
        d.date = q.date and
        q.type = 'qly_type'
where d.type = 'dly_type' and
      d.id = 1;  -- this is suspicious.  Doesn't this match only one daily row?
```

Your join conditions are suspicious.  Why are you joining on both `id` and `date`?  I wonder if that is the root of your problem.  So, I suspect you really want:

```
select d.id, d.date, d.value as dly_value, q.value as qly_value
from daily d left join
     quarterly q
     on d.date = q.date and
        q.type = 'qly_type'
where d.type = 'dly_type';
```

`Full join` is rarely needed.  If you really do need it and you want to filter both tables, then I recommend filtering in subqueries:

```
select d.id, d.date, d.value as dly_value, q.value as qly_value
from (select d.*
      from daily d
      where d.type = 'dly_type' and
            d.id = 1
     ) d full join
     (select q.*
      from quarterly q
      where q.type = 'qly_type'
     ) q
     on d.id = q.id and
        d.date = q.date
```

Comment: Thank you. The full join example with subqueries solves my problem. The join is needed on id and date as there will be multiple ids in each table (e.g. if each row had a unique key it would be id, date, type)

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select daily.id, daily.date, daily.value as dly_value, quarterly.value as qly_value
from daily
full outer join quarterly on daily.id = quarterly.id
and date_trunc('DAY',daily.date) = date_trunc('DAY',quarterly.date)
where daily.type = 'dly_type'
and quarterly.type = 'qly_type'
and daily.id = 16
```